# How to deploy php, nodejs and mysql application to IBM Cloud

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a small app written with php, node js and mysql. both php and mysql are accessing the same database table. my question is? how do I upload the app to my IBM Cloud account. and how do I start my nodejs server there?

Comment: You can easily and quickly deploy a nodejs app on the ibm cloud. The following getting started [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial) should help you set up a simple nodejs app on the cloud. Lot of online tutorials also available [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/index.html#tutorials). Just check which is relevant for you and you should be able to customise. Hope this helps